# Multiple sender profiles

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to set up for a client multiple sender profiles in one BU. They want emails to be seen as being sent from different sales people. I know this is possible through amp script, what am not sure of is if there is a total number of sender profiles I can create? if so what is it?
In addition can I create a RMM for each sender profile? In case people want to reply directly to the sender?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating multiple sender profiles, you should leverage '[Dynamic Sender Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_dynamic_sender_profile.htm&type=5)'.

> To use dynamic sender profiles with Marketing Cloud Connect, create and map attributes across clouds, and build a sender profile with those attributes. When sending the email, override the default sender profile with the custom sender profile you created.

There is also '[Create a Dynamic RMM Configuration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_dynamic_rmm_configuration.htm&type=5)'

> If you use On-Your-Behalf sends or enhanced sender profiles to build dynamic From names as part of your email sends, Reply Mail Management (RMM) can direct valid replies to those dynamic From names instead of the default email address. Contact your Marketing Cloud account representative if you want to use this feature with your RMM configuration. You must understand AMPscript to use this feature.